# Simultaneous asynchronous requests in AngularJS containing inner operation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, simultaneous

How can I create **2 simultaneous asynchronous requests** in AngularJS having one operation that has to be done after the first request ?

I want to do something like this:

- call the first web service (receive x)
- call the second web service (receive y)
- do something after I receive a response from the first web service ( f(x) )
- do something after I have both data ( g(x,y) )

The following approach:

```
 $q.all({
    x: $http.get('http://resourceX'),
    y: $http.get('http://resourceY')
}).then(function(results) {
    $scope.a = f(results.x.data);   // where to place this line ?
    $scope.z = g(results.x.data, results.y.data);
});
```

is not **efficient** because it is waiting for resourceY even if resourceX was received.

I would like to call the function f when x is available and to call the function g when x and y are available.

A pseudo-code for what I want looks like this:

```
$q.all({
    x: $http.get('http://resourceX'),
    y: $http.get('http://resourceY')
}).when(x is ready) {
    $scope.a = f(results.x.data);
}).then(function(results) {     
    $scope.z = g(results.x.data, results.y.data);
});
```

So, I want to have a performance mix between **$q.all approach** and

```
$http.get('http://resourceX').success(function(x) { 
    $scope.a = f(x);
    $http.get('http://resourceY').succes(function(y){
        $scope.z = g(x, y);     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can separate the calls this way:

```
var promiseX = $http.get('http://resourceX');
var promiseY = $http.get('http://resourceY');

promiseX.then(function(result {
    $scope.a = f(result.data);
});

$q.all({
    x: promiseX,
    y: promiseY
}).then(function(results) {
    $scope.z = g(results.x.data, results.y.data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plnkr that does what you're looking for http://plnkr.co/edit/6WER28?p=preview

```
function getX() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve('X');
    }, 300)

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  function getY() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {

      deferred.resolve('Y');
    }, 500);

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  var promiseX = getX();
  var promiseY = getY();

  promiseX.then(function(val) {
    console.log('recevied first one :' + val);
  })

  $q.all([promiseX, promiseY]).then(function(valuesFromBothInArray) {
    console.log('received both ' + valuesFromBothInArray);
  })
```